# Refreshing a UIView function with an added variable in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm using a function in my DBChartViewController.m file to pull in a value from an SQLite database and pass it to another function in my draw2D.m file in order to draw a pie chart. The view displays initially, but never actually refreshes. Is there something wrong with this implementation?

Adding rest of files:

combinedDBandPieViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"
#import "draw2D.h"

@interface combinedDBandPieViewController : UIViewController {
    draw2D *pieChart;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) draw2D *pieChart;

- (IBAction) findContact;
@end
```

combinedDBandPieViewController.m

```
#import "combinedDBandPieViewController.h"
@implementation combinedDBandPieViewController
@synthesize pieChart;
-(void)findContact
{
...code to search DB...
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *pieField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            self.pie.text = pieField;
            self.status.text = @"Match found";

            self.pieChart.ratio = [pieField floatValue];
            [self.pieChart setRatio:[pieField floatValue]];

        }
}
```

draw2D.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface draw2D : UIView {
    @public float ratio;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) float ratio;
-(void)setRatio:(float) newRatio;
@end
```

draw2D.m

```
#import "draw2D.h"
@implementation draw2D
@synthesize ratio;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect) rect{
    NSLog(@"Hurray Reached Here"); //Only comes up once, at boot
    int radius = 150;
    NSLog(@"%f", ratio);           //Only comes up once, displays 0.0000000
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 8.0);

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(84, 300, radius*2, radius*2);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 234, 450);
    CGContextAddArc(context, 234, 450, radius, 0, -(M_PI * (2*ratio)), 1);
    CGContextFillPath(context);  
}

-(void)setRatio:(float) newRatio
{
    NSLog(@"Setting Ratio");
    ratio = newRatio;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I modified my answer to be more precise on what I meant.

Comment: Remove setRatio from you .h file, @synthesize ratio creates a getter and setter for your property. Remove [self.pieChart setRatio:[pieField floatValue]] self.pieChart.ratio should be enough. Besides for that make sure you pieChart is actually initialized in your controller. Try placing an NSLog where you assign the ratio and check if pieChart is even created.

Comment: I completed the steps you suggested, and added the following NSLog calls:

[self.pieChart setRatio:[pieField floatValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", pieField);  //returns .5
NSLog(@"%f", self.pieChart.ratio); //returns 0.000000

Comment: What about NSLog(@"%@",self.pieChart);

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",self.pieChart);// returns (null)

Comment: Alright that means your pieChart was never even created. How do you initialize your pieChart? Do you use Interface Builder (Story Board)?

Comment: Wouldn't declaring it like I did in my combinedDBandPieViewController.h file do it?

Comment: Ah, I found the solution. By appending IBOutlet before the statement (IBOutlet draw2D *pieChart;) and by going into the Interface Builder and dragging the pieChart to the view, everything works perfectly now. Thank you Joel!

Comment: You would need to make your pieChart property an IBOutlet then connect your UIView in story board to the your pieChart property. You should also make sure to set your UIView in storyboard to the custom class draw2D.

Comment: Opps a little to slow on the response on my part. Glad everything worked out. If I did answer your question could you select my answer as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see above you are trying to create a view that uses a ratio to display a pie chart. In this case you would want to use the ratio to control what your view renders. I would modify the code to make the ratio a property of your view and whenever the ratio property is changed the view refreshes itself.

Expected behaviour

```
- (void) findContact
{
   ...code which pull value from database and displays correctly...
   NSString *passingPie = pieField;
   self.piechart.ratio = [passingPie floatValue];
}
```

.h file

```
@interface PieChartView : UIView{

    @public
    float ratio;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) float ratio;
```

.m file

```
@implementation PieChartView
@synthesize ratio;

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
  int radius = 400;
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 8.0);

  CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(184, 300, radius, radius);
  CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
  CGContextFillPath(context);

  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
  CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 384, 500);
  CGContextAddArc(context, 384, 500, 200, 0, -(M_PI * (2*ratio)), 1);
  CGContextFillPath(context);
}

- (void) setRatio:(float)newRatio{
  ratio = newRatio;
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried your method, but it's still not working. I tried adding an NSLog message inside the setRatio function, but it is never getting called....

Comment: Then try calling setRatio directly [self.piechart setRatio:[passingPie floatValue]];

Comment: Same thing :( It compiles and runs fine (except for the unpassed variable), would posting my entire project help?

Comment: Don't need to post the entire project just the relevant files.